# Axios - Simple way of querying and storing paginated response data

Tags: javascript, axios, concatenation

I have a basic async function that retrieves a list of users using Axios. The response from the Discourse API I am calling is paginated to include 50 users per page - I need to invoke the same call 5 times to get all the users, as the script below shows.. the only parameter that changes is `&page=`

```
const [one, two, three, four, five] = await Promise.all([
    axios.get(`https://meta.discourse.org/directory_items.json?order=days_visited&page=0&period=all`),
    axios.get(`https://meta.discourse.org/directory_items.json?order=days_visited&page=1&period=all`),
    axios.get(`https://meta.discourse.org/directory_items.json?order=days_visited&page=2&period=all`),
    axios.get(`https://meta.discourse.org/directory_items.json?order=days_visited&page=3&period=all`),
    axios.get(`https://meta.discourse.org/directory_items.json?order=days_visited&page=4&period=all`)
  ]);

var users_array = one.data.directory_items.concat(two.data.directory_items, three.data.directory_items, four.data.directory_items, five.data.directory_items)
```

While this works, it seems cumbersome and I am wondering if there is a more concise and efficient way of doing this?

Comment: How do you know you will get all the users if you do this? What if there's more over time, what if there's less? If you really want to load all data, you should run a loop until you're sure you have all pages...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
// create Array containing all calls
const calls = [...Array(5).keys()].map(x => 
axios.get(`https://meta.discourse.org/directory_items.json?order=days_visited&page=${x}&period=all`)
)

// This will ensure that all api calls happen parallely
const [one, two, three, four, five] = await Promise.all(calls);

var users_array = one.data.directory_items.concat(two.data.directory_items, three.data.directory_items, four.data.directory_items, five.data.directory_items)
```

Comment: @ogot Consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) answer if it helped you